# Can't get PHP errors to go to a log file (other than the Apache log)

Tags: php, apache, lamp, error-reporting, error-log

On a Ubuntu web server [LAMP], I'm trying to get PHP errors to write into a php_error file, but no matter what I do, they keep going to the apache log.

Here's what I have tried/done:

1. Edited the php.ini file:

   - error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
   - display_error   = Off
   - log_errors      = On
   - error_log       = /var/log/php_errors.log
2. Restarted Apache
3. Checked the `phpinfo()` output to verify that the changes I made to the php.ini file took -- they did.
4. After verifying that the errors were still going to the Apache log, I physically created the php_errors.log and tried again.  Still going to the Apache log!
5. Rebooted the web server!  Still...!

Anybody have a solution?

Comment: check `log_errors_max_len` is greater than 0

Comment: And does the web server have permission to create `/var/log/php_errors.log`? You may need to place that inside a location Apache can write to like `/var/log/httpd/php_errors.log` or `/var/log/apache2/php_errors.log`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It had to do with ownership.  One or the other has worked [for reasons that are not clear to me]:

```
chown www-data:www-data /var/log/php_error.log

chown same-user-as-www-home:same-user-as-web-home /var/log/php_error.log
```

Also, the following has made a difference:

```
chmod 664 /var/log/php_error.log
```

[as opposed to chmod 644...again for reasons that are not clear to me]

Answer (score 2):

Check the directory permissions for `/var/log`. Ensure that the user your Web service is running as has write permissions to that folder. Alternatively, create a subfolder (/var/log/phplogs?) and assign explicit permissions on that for the user in question then change the `error_log` value to be a file in *that* folder

Answer (score 0):

For the record, Ubuntu uses **AppArmor** and it limits what Apache does.

Additionally, to change the permissions to the file and editing the php.ini file, you must do the next steps:

Go to the next file

> /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions

Edit this file

> apache2-common

Add the next line

```
/var/log/php_errors.log rw,
```

where **rw** means the process could read and write this file

or you could also do:

```
sudo nano /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/apache2-common
```

And finally, reload the configuration of **apparmor**

```
systemctl reload  apparmor
```

Note: Centos/Redhat/Oracle Linux uses SELinux and it requires the same step but the configuration is different.